# Define condition to Class

Tags: python

I am trying to define condition to class, if my object Does not meet the conditions:

The conditions: all the organs is vectors, the shape of the vectors is the same.

When I try to casting the object the function will return `None`.

Thats what I tried so far:

```
class Matrix:
    def __init__(self,m1):
        dic_len = {}
        self.m1 = tuple(m1)
        checking = 0
        for i in self.m1:
            dic_len[len(i)] = 'check'
            if type(i) != Vector:
                self.m1 = None
                checking = 1
        if len(dic_len) != 1:
            self.m1 = None
        if len(dic_len) == 1 and checking == 0:
            self.content = self.m1 = tuple(m1)
            self.shape = (len(m1),len(m1[0]))

    def __repr__(self):
        if self.m1 != None:
            return "(" + ", ".join(str(i) for i in self.m1) + ")"
        else:
            return None
```

But I get this error:

```
>>>v1 = Vector([1,2])
>>>v2 = Vector([4,5,6])
>>>m = Matrix([v1,v2])
>>>print(m)
TypeError: __str__ returned non-string (type NoneType)
```

i wish the function will return None.

Answer (score 2):

```
return str(None)
```

instead of

```
return None
```

Answer (score 1):

The CPython [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__repr__) state for the `__repr__` method state that

> The return value **must** be a string object.

So returning `None` isn't going to work.

```
>>> class C:
...     def __repr__(self):
...         return None
... 

>>> c = C()
>>> repr(c)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: __repr__ returned non-string (type NoneType)
```

If you're going to share your code with others, it might be better to code `__repr__` to produce its coventional output:

> ...this should look like a valid Python expression that could be used to recreate an object with the same value (given an appropriate environment)...

And override `__str__` to produce a representation that indicates the validity of the object instance (though note `__str__` must also return a string).